# Does the 4th dialog level of asp.net website work on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

In asp.net (c#) website, I have 4th level of dialog work correctly in computer browsers but not work in mobile browsers , and  its parents 1st ,2nd and 3rd are work correctly in both computer and mobile browsers , does the 4th level of dialog not supported in mobile browser ?

Comment: Before you ask a question, please read these- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes it should so. All you need to do is program it correctly .